How to make a transition between 2 objects (between their materials, as in the picture)
I have 2 identical models of tractor, the first has a lot of materials. the 2nd has only one half-transparent material. how do I make the same transition (animation) as in the attached picture?

Hello and welcome. Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

At first blush this is easiest to accomplish with two different complete renders and fade between the two videos in your video editor.  That way you don't have to render again for small changes.

Yup this looks like a simple usecase for view layers : render with material 1, render with material 2, use a gradient with an alpha over node to composite the two

You can use a Separate XYZ plugged into a ColorRamp as factor between your 2 shaders (transparent and opaque or whatever). Use the Mapping location value if you want to move the separation:

